# Ethernet not working on Loki

Tags: release-loki, ubuntu, ethernet

My Ethernet is not working on elementary os loki. I have tried updating the driver to the r8168 driver and that does not seem to help. Looks like everything is installed properly , however, when I plug in the Ethernet cable, nothing happens. Its like as if the cable was unplugged from the other side. I have checked to make sure the cable is working fine as the same setup works on another laptop that is running windows.

Here is some relevant information from some commands that might be useful:

```
$ lsmod | grep r816*
r8168                 487424  0

$ uname -a
Linux Z50 4.4.0-72-generic #93-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 31 14:07:41 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ sudo lshw -c NET       
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 10
       serial: 68:f7:28:ad:ac:5a
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.041.00-NAPI duplex=full latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:43 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c0504000-c0504fff memory:c0500000-c0503fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3160
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 93
       serial: 34:e6:ad:01:09:eb
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-72-generic firmware=17.352738.0 ip=192.168.1.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:49 memory:c0400000-c0401fff

$ ifconfig -a
enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 68:f7:28:ad:ac:5a  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:183 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:22814 (22.8 KB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:43 Base address:0x8000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:512 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:512 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:75048 (75.0 KB)  TX bytes:75048 (75.0 KB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 34:e6:ad:01:09:eb  
          inet addr:192.168.1.4  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a3d4:c27e:c456:fb17/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:349200 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:68004 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:525237555 (525.2 MB)  TX bytes:7102805 (7.1 MB)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else suffering from this issue, it got resolved after I uninstalled all the proprietary drivers for the Ethernet and used only the free ones.